# Quisiera saber cómo funciona el proceso bajo este código para que me dé el resultado que no espero

Tags: javascript, html5, programacion-asincrona

Haciendo una pequeña prueba hice este código:

```js
arr = ["item", "item2", "item3"]

var li = document.createElement("li")

arr.forEach(item =>{
    
    li.textContent = item 
    
           console.log(li)
})
```

El resultado que esperaba en la consola era dicha etiqueta `li` con el contenido actual del recorrido del bucle, las veces que este se repite(3), o sea, `<li>ítem</li>` , `<li>item2</li>` y `<li>item3</li>`, pero resulta que me lanzó solamente el contenido del último elemento del Array, o sea,`<li>item3</li>` las 3 veces del recorrido y sé que es porque no estoy incluyendo el `createElement` dentro del `forEach` pero... Quiero saber ¿por qué sucede esto así dejando el `createElement` fuera? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se que estas probando ni donde. Pero aca se ve bien

Comment: Con el código que pusiste el resultado es correcto, cada elemento aparece en la consola. ¿Tu código real es como este? Puede haber gran diferencia si involucras promesas.

Comment: El código es exactamente el mismo, lo copié, y el resultado es así como en la imagen, me devuelve la etiqueta li con el contenido del último elemento del Array las 3 veces

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

El problema, es que al hacer un `console.log` de un objeto, no está mostrando el estado del objeto en ese momento en concreto (como si lo hace la herramienta de esta web), si no un "**enlace**" a ese objeto, de manera que al abrir su contenido mostrará los valores del estado actual.
Si muestras una propiedad en concreto, si mostrará el valor en ese momento.
Por ejemplo:

```js
arr = ["item", "item2", "item3"]
var li = document.createElement("li")
arr.forEach(item =>{
  li.textContent = item 
  console.log(li, li.textContent)
})
```

Si lo pruebas, veràs que la propiedad `li.textContent` la muestra correctamente, pero `li` es un enlace al objeto, de manera que mostrará el estado actual.

**EDIT 2**
Otro tema es el funcionamiento del navegador a la hora de mostrar la información.
Por ejemplo,si después del `console.log` pones un `window.prompt` para parar la ejecución (solo **firefox**, en los otros no mostrará el `log` hasta finalizar el bucle) y poder ver la salida antes de terminar el bucle, si pulsas el enlace cargará el valor en ese momento, y quedará guardado en el `log`, pero si no pulsas y lo haces luego, mostrará el último en los tres enlaces.
Resumiendo, no muestres objetos por `log`, muestra sus propiedades.

Comment: si bro, solo he creado un elemento pero en ese caso deberia pintarse por consola solo una vez el resultado no? o como es? soy novato en esto recien estoy comenzando a escribir codigo

Comment: segun yo supongo que el loop pasa todos los elemntos del array automatico al ultimo ya que el li es uno solo pero tambien pienso que en ese caso debe pintarse por consola un solo resultado, porque me tira 3? esa es mi duda

Comment: Aunque solo hagas un objeto, el bucle itera 3 veces, así que, como el console.log está dentro el bucle, lo ejecutará 3 veces, mostrando la información de ese único objeto, con sus diferentes valores, que varia en cada iteración. Al final se queda con el último que se le ha asignado.
El texto del li primero vale "item1" y lo muestra por consola, después lo cambias por "item2" y lo muestra por consola, y luego, en su ultima iteracion, lo vuelve a cambiar por "item3", lo vuelve a mostrar, y sale del bucle.

Comment: aah ya, exacto, ahora creo entender, a eso me referia yo al principio, que el console deberia mostrar los 3 diferentes valores en cada iteracion, asi como dices que primero vale "item1" luego "item2" e "item3" pero solamente muestra "item3" las 3 veces y segun lo que entiendo supongo que el bucle en la primera pasada le asigna todos los elementos quedando en el ultimo y lo pasa por consola las 3 veces que deberia correr el ciclo? corrigeme si me equivoco porfa, creo que no tiene mucho sentido nose

Comment: Si el console.log lo pones fuera del bucle, si, solo mostraría el último, pero en el ejemplo que pones, está dentro, y muestra los tres valores, como indica @gbianchi en el comentario.

Comment: Si claro Bro, con el console.log dentro me tira 3 resultados pero todos con el contenido del último elemento del Array o sea, "item3", no debería ir mostrando todos los ítems conforme al recorrido del bucle así como tú dices? Porque no lo hace, solo muestra el "item3" todo el recorrido

Comment: No lo sé, pero es una locura, parece como si fuera un error o algo así, porqué es como que así haya un solo "li" en el bucle, este solo va a ir cambiando y de ley tiene que mostrar por consola el contenido o cambio actual por el cual va pasando el bucle, porque de otra forma sería como si en la primera iteración se recorrieron todos los elementos del Array quedando en el último y aplicándolo al "li" y mostrandolo por consola lo cual no tiene sentido porque igual se muestra 3 veces, y porqué 3 veces? Si ya ha pasado por todos los elementos del Array desde la primera iteración? ...

Comment: Es que en el ejemplo que pones, no ocurre lo de mostar solo "item3", muestra "item", "item2" y "item3".

Comment: Si, lo puse como ejemplo del resultado que buscaba, pero no es el resultado que me da, solo me muestra el "item3" las 3 veces como ya he dicho antes Bro

Comment: Ahí puse una foto

Comment: Edité la respuesta.

Comment: Si, así como dices también lo he probado y si me ha funcionado, por ese lado entiendo cómo que a lo que se le está haciendo el cambio como tal es al texto del interior de la etiqueta y no a la etiqueta completa en si, y que por lo tanto si yo mando por consola la propiedad en concreto que estoy asignadole el valor("li.textContent") y no el objeto completo como tal("li"), es ese el que se va a mostrar...

Comment: Entonces esto querría decir que el bucle pasa por el "li.textContent" más no por el "li" completo que es el que se manda por consola.... Entonces el bucle itera por el Array aplicándole los valores a "li.textContent" pero al momento de pasar por consola el "li" es como que ya ha pasado todo el recorrido quedando al último ya que es un solo "li" pero al "li.textContent" se le siguen asignando y cambiando sus valores en el recorrido....Es así como funciona entonces??

Comment: 'li.textcontent' es una de las varias propiedades del objeto 'li', i la única que modifica el bucle. Lo que muestra por consola, es un enlace al objeto "li", y cuando lo pulses mostrará el estado que tiene en ese momento. Como cuando pulses ese enlace, el bucle ya habrá terminado, entonces veras el valor final, pero si pulsaras el enlace antes que terminara, mostraría los otros valores.

Comment: He añadido algo mas en la respuesta.